# What does the column and rows for images in TensorBoard mean?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I was trying to use the tensorflow `tf. image_summary` but it wasn't clear to me how to use it. In the [tensorboard readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md) file they have the following sentence that confuses me:

> The dashboard is set up so that each row corresponds to a different
>   tag, and each column corresponds to a run.

I don't understand the sentence and thus, I am having a hard time figuring out what the columns and rows mean for TensorBoard image visualization. What exactly is a "tag" and what exactly is a "run"? How do I get multiple "tags" and multiple "runs" to display? Why would I want multiple "tags" and "runs" to display?

Does someone have a very simple but non-trivial example of how to use this?

Ideally, what I want to use is compare how my model performs with respect to PCA so in my head it would be nice to compare how the reconstructions compare to PCA reconstruction at each step. Not sure if this is a good idea but I also want to see what the activation images look like and how the templates look like.

---

Curenttly I have a very simple script with the following lines:

```
with tf.name_scope('input_reshape'):
    x_image = tf.to_float(x, name='ToFloat')
    image_shaped_input = tf.reshape(x_image, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
    tf.image_summary('input', image_shaped_input, 10)
```

currently I have managed to discover that the rows are of length 10 so i assume its showing me 10 images that have something to do with the current run/batch.

[image]

however, if possible I'd like to see reconstruction, filters (currently I am doing fully connected to keep things simple but eventually it would be nice to see a conv net examples), activation units (with any number of units that I choose), etc.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow was officially released (r1.0) after this question was posed, and the functions and documentation accompanying Tensorboard have been simplified.

`tf.summary.image` is now the Op for writing images represented by a 4D Tensor to the summary file; here is the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image).

To answer your questions about rows and columns, each call to `tf.summary.image` generates a new tag or row of image summaries with the total number dictated by the value passed as `max_outputs` (10 in your given example).

As to why one might want to view more than one column of data, If the first dimension of the 4D Tensor is greater than 1 (i.e. batch size > 1), it will be helpful to see more than one column in Tensorboard to get a better sense of the entire batch of images.

Finally, having multiple tags is helpful when wanting to view two different collections of images, such as input images and reconstructed images if you were building an autoencoder architecture.